# Ownership of COM objects in UI Automation callbacks

Tags: c++, com

UI Automation callbacks, such as [`IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler::HandleFocusChangedEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696052.aspx), receive an `[in]` parameter `IUIAutomationElement *sender`.

Should the event handler call `Release()` on this object?

Comment: No, you shouldn't release `[in]` parameters. They are owned by the caller.

Comment: See [Rules for Managing Reference Counts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692481.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller is always responsible for releasing any function arguments in COM.

The event handler should not decrement the reference count.